# Finding $K_{3,3}, K_{5}$ as subgraphs

Tags: discrete-mathematics, planar-graphs

Hey I am supposed to determine if this graph is planar. I know, that it is not. But I failed to find $K_{3,3}, K_{5}$ as subgraphs.

[image]

Can anyone help?

Comment: The reason you can't find those subgraphs is because it is planar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You failed to find those...that should tell you that it *is* planar, which is true.

To see these, move the two top-most nodes. Move the right one to the SE of the lower right node. Move the left one downward until it's just below the long diagonal from NW to SE.

Short summary: When what you observe and what you "know" are in contradiction, it's time to question what you know.

Comment: Thanks, but how can you see it? I thought that it is not planar because I cannot draw it without intersecting the edges.. I did not thought about moving the vertices

Comment: The graph itself is just a collection called the "vertices" and a list of pairs of vertices. The locations of the dots and arcs in the plane are up to you --- *those* choices constitute an embedding. How can I "see" where to move the nodes? I've got 50 years of practice. There are algorithms, but for graphs this small, just messing around works well. You might want to visit "planarity.net" for a fun game that lets you practice this a little bit.

Comment: @PeterF. Also see the game Untangle https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/puzzles/js/untangle.html There are also free (with no ads) phone app versions of this puzzle collection.

Comment: @JohnHughes Thank you so much, I will try it

Comment: @PM2Ring Thank you so much